# images displaying one below another in smaller screens

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

we are using below code to display 4 images, but its not responsive as in [link1](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/couples.html) , mainly the middle 2 images in 2nd row is displaying one below the other in smaller screens.

if anyone want : [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v692c2e1/)

we are using similar code in [link2](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/) but this looks responsive.

```css
.top-designs1 > h1, .mens-block > h1, .womens-collection > h1, .fan-book > h1 {color: #000;padding-top: 5px;text-align: center;}
 .tow-grid1 .left {float: left;width: 50%;}
 .tow-grid1 .right {float: right;width: 50%;}
 .full-grid1 {margin-bottom: 10px;}
```

```html
<div class="top-designs1">
<div class="tow-grid1">

<div class="full-grid1">
<img src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/wysiwyg/a1.jpg" width="1000px" />
</div>

<div style="clear: both; margin-bottom: -10px;">&nbsp;
</div>

<div class="left">
<img src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/wysiwyg/a2.jpg"}}" width="495px" />
</div>

<div class="right">
<img src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/wysiwyg/a3.jpg"}}" width="495px" />
</div>


<div style="clear: both; margin-bottom: -10px;">&nbsp;
</div>


<div class="full-grid1">
<img src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/wysiwyg/a4.jpg" width="1000px" />
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several things colliding there, i don't know if you are using some grid system or that you made it yourself but I put together a small example using flexbox so you can take a look (I believe it's much cleaner than what you have).

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300">
  </div>
</div>

.grid {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 1024px;
}

.item {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  min-width: 350px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/pedromrb/pen/EZNBQZ

Hope it helps, you can resize it to see it wrap.

Any question feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks, i followed your way in [link3](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/pedro) but still 2nd and 3rd images are displaying one below the other, but it should display in same row as in [link1](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/couples.html)

Comment: sure, you can edit the pen if you like, I'm not understading from the examples which behaviour do you want.

Do you want 3 rows, with the 2nd row wrapping?

Comment: yes, i want 4 images to display , `1st row - 1 image 2nd row - 2 images , 3rd row - 1 image`

Comment: i will  use your code & create new fiddle to give to you

Comment: please check, i used your code and included 4 images as per my requirement : https://jsfiddle.net/ruq76hj3/

Comment: you can check , in fidle also its displayinjg 2 images in 2nd row displaying one below the other : http://prnt.sc/dx4zwz

Comment: from what i understood you want this, https://jsfiddle.net/ruq76hj3/5/

can you explain how it needs to wrap?

Comment: i updated your code in site & its working fine for 1st and last image,  but 2nd and 3rd images are displaying one below the other, can you please help me to solve this, i want to display 2nd and 3rd image in one row as like [here](http://stylebaby.com/cases-covers/couples.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help..... i missed somewhere, your solution was working fine......

Answer (score 0):

Can you check with this if you want to make image responsive

```
 .top-designs1 img{ width:100%; display:block;}
```

Comment: Thanks, i need to give space b/w each row [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/pedro) , can you please help to give space as like [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cases-covers/couples.html)

Comment: space below images ?